# ssh on linux connects using public key, on macos fails with same public key

Tags: linux, ssh, macos

I copied my public and private key to MacOS and wanted to check that I'm able to connect to a remote server like I can from Linux.

And to my surprise I can't, something rejects the same key when I'm on MacOS, and accepts it when I'm on Linux.

Here's a snipped form MacOS:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: my-key RSA SHA256:SOME_HASH agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

While on Linux I get:

```
debug1: Offering public key: my-key RSA SHA256:SOME_HASH explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: my-key RSA SHA256:SOME_HASH explicit agent
```

Why? I don't see any errors except the packet type 51 on MacOS and type 60 on Linux.
The key files are exactly the same, same hashes.

Is there a way to debug it why it is rejected? I used `-vvvvv` (adding more than three `v` doesn't change anything I think).

Comment: If you can switch logging on, on the server, it'll explain why it rejects the offered key

Comment: @XTian The issue is that I don't control the server